# Kafka Streams Topology stuck in num.stream.threads=50 and 100 partitions

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

There is a topology:

```
kStreamBuilder.stream(kafkaProperties.getInboundTopicName(), consumed)
            .filterNot((k,v) -> Objects.isNull(v))
            .transform(() -> new CustomTransformer(...))
            .transform(() -> new AnotherTransformer(...))
            .to(kafkaProperties.getOutTopicName(), resultProduced);
```

with configured

```
num.stream.threads: 50
```

On startup application stuck with constantly logging messages(I'm not 100% sure it stuck but after 20 minutes there are no changes in the state and CPU, network usage is very high) :

```
State transition from RUNNING to PARTITIONS_REVOKED    
AbstractCoordinator          : [Consumer clientId=consumer_id-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=group_id] (Re-)joining group
AbstractCoordinator          : [Consumer clientId=consumer_id-StreamThread-2-consumer, groupId=group_id] (Re-)joining group
AbstractCoordinator          : [Consumer clientId=consumer_id-StreamThread-3-consumer, groupId=group_id] (Re-)joining group
AbstractCoordinator          : [Consumer clientId=consumer_id-StreamThread-4-consumer, groupId=group_id] (Re-)joining group
AbstractCoordinator          : [Consumer clientId=consumer_id-StreamThread-5-consumer, groupId=group_id] (Re-)joining group
```

etc.

Topic has 100 partitions.

What we noticed: every transformer uses it's own persistentStateStore. After replacing it to inMemoryStateStore there still were logs written above but after ~3 minutes topology started successfully.

Kafka streams version 2.1.0. 
Broker version 1.1.0

Comment: Hard to say. It seems that threads drop out of the consumer group. Maybe try to increase `session.timeout.ms`?

Comment: Tried and it didn't help. With less number of num.stream.threads: 32 it works well. Yes it logs couple of times the same things but after couple of minutes it started up successfully.

Comment: Maybe you can increase broker setting `group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms` -- note, this only is affective on startup if you have an empty consumer group.