# Kafka streams listening to multiple topics hangs

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm working with the kafka streams api and am running into issues where I subscribe to multiple topics and the consumer just hangs. It has a unique `application.id` and I can see in kafka that the consumer group has been created, but when I describe the group, I'll get: `consumer group X has no active members`. I've left it running for close to an hour.

The interesting thing is that this works when the `topics` list only contains 1 topic. I'm not interested in other answers where we create multiple sources, ie: `source1 = builder.stream("topic1")` and `source2 = builder.stream("topic2")` as the interface for `StreamsBuilder.stream` supports an array of topics.

I've been able to subscribe to multiple topics before, I just can't replicate how we've done this. (This code is running in a different environment and working as expected, so not sure if it's a timing issue or something else)

```
List<String> topics = Arrays.asList("topic1", "topic2");

StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
KStream<String, String> source = builder.stream(topics);

source
.transformValues(...)
.map(key, value) -> ...)
.to((key, value, record) -> ...);

new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), props).start();
```

**UPDATE 06/18/19**
After enabling logs, it was clear that we were trying to subscribe & publish to topics that did not exist. While we had `auto.topic.create.enable=true` it didn't matter. So ultimately had a check on startup that would cause the script to exit if all the topics weren't created beforehand since we weren't creating topics dynamically.

Comment: I also previously faced with such issue. in my case, it was due to State Store with enabled logging. on app start, Kafla Streams reread all data from State Store internal topic. if you have a lot of data in this topic, app start will take a lot of time. you could test your code with disabled logging, it should fix your problem, but app will not be fault tolerant. also please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55284592/kafka-streams-topology-stuck-in-num-stream-threads-50-and-100-partitions

Comment: Kafka streams require you to create all the source topic in advance. If one of the source topics does not exist it will still failed to start (I think it's better than just ignoring non-existing topics but error message can be improved.). `auto.topic.create.enable=true` does not work because you are trying to consume not publish.